# Bootsrap Flex and Justify-Content not working

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I just create footer with 4 columns, and last column contain two rows of div. I want that last column to be left aligned so i use justify-content-start for the first row, and it works. But when i try it to second row, which is search bar with button, the justify-content-start doesn't work.

So I tried with flex-row, but it doesn't work either. Here is my web view right now.

[image]

I want that search bar and button are parallel with the visitor counter above. Any suggestions for me to fix this things up?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
  <div class="row mb-4 justify-content-start">
    <div class="card text-white visitor-card" style="width: 16rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Total Pengunjung :</h5>
        <?php 
            $date  = date("Y-m-d");
            $pengunjunghariini  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM visitor WHERE date='".$date."' GROUP BY ip")->num_rows(); // Hitung jumlah pengunjung
            $dbpengunjung = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(hits) as hits FROM visitor")->row(); 
            $totalpengunjung = isset($dbpengunjung->hits)?($dbpengunjung->hits):0; // hitung total pengunjung
            $bataswaktu = time() - 300;
            $pengunjungonline  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM visitor WHERE online > '".$bataswaktu."'")->num_rows(); // hitung pengunjung online`
        ?>

        <h5 class="card-title">
          <?php echo $totalpengunjung ?>
        </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="border-color: white;">
    <div>
      <form class="d-flex" action="<?= base_url('Home/search'); ?>" method="post">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Cari artikel ..." aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap offers [borders with color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/borders/#color). No need to write custom styles (which shouldn't be in your markup anyway--use CSS classes).

Comment: I see several issues which makes it difficult to provide a good answer. I'm not sure what your goals are. 1) You're using rows without nested columns. Bootstrap uses offsetting margins for those. This makes your card wider than it should be, so it only _appears_ that your form isn't left-aligned. It is. 2) You're using raw flex containers for the form. Why not use the same grid structure for both rows? 3) Your card has a hard-coded width. This makes it stretch outside its container in some cases. Your content should fit your grid, but if you fix widths you need to be sure there's room for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your container of that search bar might already have 100% width of its parent, so that any horizontal alignment wont be possible, since it has no space to move to.

This is a very common issue, and to quickly find out what is going on, you can use some CSS debugging techniques, as weird as it sounds.

The best example of this layout debugging technique is to set a border to your div that you need to be aligned somehow (or on its children).

```
.container {
   border: 1px solid lime
   outline: 1px solid lime
}
```

*Note: outline might be better in some cases, since it is not increasing width/height of your element*

If your container is really as wide as its parent, try `width: fit-content` on it, so it shrinks and leaves some space to be aligned to. Hope this helps, and to the future as well :-)